# Running a script when connecting to server with ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

I use the kitty terminal emulator, so when I connect to a new server, I (usually) need to ad the terminfo (at least, this way it seems to work). To do this I wrote a script. While I was at it, I added a bit of code to add a public key if the user wants it to.
Not really relevant for the question, but here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=$1
ip=$(echo $host | cut -d@ -f2 | cut -d: -f1)
# Check if it is a unknown host
if [[ -z $(ssh-keygen -F $ip) ]]; then
    # Check if there are any ssh-keys
    if [ $(ls $HOME/.ssh/*.pub > /dev/null | wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then
        keys=$(echo $( (cd $HOME/.ssh/ && ls *.pub) | sed "s/.pub//g" ))
        ssh -q -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no $host "ls > /dev/null 2>&1"
        # Check if the server has one of the public keys
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Do you want to add a SSh key to the server?"
            while true; do
                read -p " Choose [$keys] or leave empty to skip: " key
                if [[ -z $key ]]; then
                    break
                elif [[ -e $HOME/.ssh/$key ]]; then
                    # Give the server a public key
                    ssh $host "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && echo \"$(cat $HOME/.ssh/$key.pub)\" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
                    break
                else
                    echo "No key with the name \"$key\" found."
                fi
            done
        fi
    fi
    # Copy terminfo to server
    ssh -t $host "echo \"$(infocmp -x)\" > \"\$TERM.info\" && tic -x \"\$TERM.info\" && rm \$TERM.info"
fi
```

It is not the best code, but it seems to work. Tips are ofcourse welcome.

The problem is that I need to run this script every time I connect te a new remote server (or I need to keep track of which server is new, but that is even worse). Is there a way to run this script every time I connect to a server (the script checks if the ip is a known host).
Or is there an other way to do this? Adding the public keys is nice to have, but not very important.

I hope somone can help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to identify that you are using `ssh` to login on the target machine:

```
pgrep -af "sshd.*"$USER |wc -l
```

The above command will count the user's processes using `sshd`

You can add the above command in the target machine, to test if you are connected via `ssh`. Add the above command to your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` script in the target machine.

So that only if you login via `ssh` your script will run initiation script on the target machine when you login/connect.

#### Sample `.bash_profile` on target machine

```
#!/bin/bash
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
if [[ $(pgrep -af "sshd.*"$USER |wc -l) -gt 0 ]];  then
    your_init_script
fi
```

Comment: This is the wrong way around. My local machine should run my script, every time I try to connect to an unknown target machine.